# Spring JPA + Hibernate to get the unrelated data

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need some help with spring jpa and hibernate. I am novice to both these technologies, trying with few solutions without luck. So thought asking the experts.

We have 3 database tables:

Table 1: Member

```
+----------------+
| id   |   Name  |
+------+---------+
|  M1  | Member1 |
+------+---------+
```

Table 2: Account

```
+----------------------+
|  id |  Member_id(FK) |
+-----|----------------+
|  A1 |     M1         |
|-----|----------------|
|  A2 |     M1         |
|-----|----------------|
|  A3 |     M1         |
+-----+----------------+
```

Table 3: Limit

```
+-------+---------+----------------+
|   ID  |  LIMIT  | ACCOUNT_ID(FK) |
+-------+---------+----------------+
|   L1  |  1000   | A2             |
+-------+---------+----------------+
```

Member.java

```
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBERSHIP")
public class Member implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

Account.java

```
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID")
    private Member member;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage =         CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "account",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private List<Limit> limits = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Limit.java

```
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "LIMIT")
public class Limit implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    //    @JoinFormula("select ACCOUNT_ID from LIMIT where ACCOUNT_ID in " +
    //            "(select id from ACCOUNT where MEMBER_ID = :MEMBER_ID)")

    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT")
    //    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
    //            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(select     ACCOUNT_ID from LIMIT where ACCOUNT_ID in (select id from ACCOUNT where MEMBER_ID     = :MEMBER_ID))", referencedColumnName="CLEARING_MEMBER_ID"))
    //            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn("MEMBER_ID",     referencedColumnName="MEMBER_ID"))
    //    })

    private Account account;

}
```

Now, with the above setup and code, when I get the list of Accounts, I get the limit that is configured for each account. But the requirement is to get the list of limits for any account for the member, which this account is part of.

So, current query looks like:

```
Select * from limit where account_id = ?
```

The expected query I want from the JPA to execute would be:

```
Select * from limit l, account a, member m
where l.account_id = a.id
and a.member_id = m.id
and m.id = ?
```

Here the value of ? would be account.member.id

I know the database structure is wrong, which doesn't fit the business requirement but I can't change it now, it's legacy.

I have tried many solutions like trying to see if I can use **@JoinFormula** but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

These changes might help you,

In Member Entity,

```
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBERSHIP")
public class Member implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "member",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<Account> accounts;
}
```

In Account Entity,

```
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "MEMBER_ID",
        referencedColumnName="id")
private Member member;

@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage =         CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "account",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<Limit> limits;
}
```

In Limit entity,

```
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "LIMIT")
public class Limit implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID",
       referencedColumnName="id")
private Account account;
}
```

This will not work Unless you add @PrePersist and @PreRemove methods in Entity.

Example:
In Member Entity,

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    if (org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(accounts)) {
        accounts.forEach(account -> {
            account.setMember(this);
            account.prePersist();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my issue but I am not talking about persisting the data. The issue described above is purely for retrieval of the data. No insert/update/delete of the data is required.

Comment: yeah, in the same way, retrieval of data can be done. no need to query for account and limits, just get the member to access all the accounts and its corresponding limits